# Most efficient way to transform arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to transform this array of objects into another array of objects but outputed in a different way. What's the most efficient method and /or faster (in terms of performance if there's a huge amount of arrays)? Should I use a for...on, lodash, filter, or reduce?
thank you

```
let array = [
 {
   "years": "2017", "opex": 90000, "netRevenue": 50000, "payroll": 60000, "rent":20000, "marketing":5000, "other":5000
 },
 {
   "years": "2018", "opex": 108500, "netRevenue": 55000, "payroll": 70000, "rent":22500, "marketing":10000, "other":6000
 },
 {
   "years": "2019", "opex": 153000, "netRevenue": 120000, "payroll": 100000, "rent":25000, "marketing":20000, "other":8000
 },
]
```

to

```
let array = {
 "opex":{
  "2017":90000, "2018":108500, "2019":153000
 },
 "netRevenue":{
  "2017":50000, "2018":55000, "2019":120000
 },
 "payroll":{
  "2017":60000, "2018":70000, "2019":100000
 },
 "rent":{
  "2017":20000, "2018":22500, "2019":25000
 },
 "marketing":{
  "2017":5000, "2018":10000, "2019":20000
 },
 "other":{
  "2017":5000, "2018":6000, "2019":8000
 }
}
```

UPDATE
Added with double quotation marks where needed

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transform"? There are different array methods and it'd be helpful to know what kind of output you expect :)

Comment: what you are expecting is a keyed array which is not possible are you sure you want array or object as final output ??

Comment: Use whatever you want and feel comfortable with. If you have something that works test your project with a profiler. And only if the transformation of the arrays is the bottleneck begin optimizing it.

Comment: Well, I suspect he got the brackets for the output object mixed up: `[]` instead of `{}` ...

Comment: its nothing, is what i was trying to emphasise.. as as for the expected its and array which does not contain a valid object

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is not a valid array but you can accomplish this with an object instead

1. first you will loop over the array and
2. get the year value
3. then get all the keys to the object
4. check to make sure the key is not 'years' as you dont want that in your result per spec
5. check to see if that key exists in the resultObject
6. if not then create a new object with the elements key
7. if it does then add the the element at the objects key

```js
let array = [{years: 2018, opex: 90000, netRevenue: 50000, payroll: 60000, rent:20000, marketing:5000, other:5000},{years: 2018, opex: 108500, netRevenue: 55000, payroll: 70000, rent:22500, marketing:10000, other:6000},{years: 2019, opex: 153000, netRevenue: 120000, payroll: 100000, rent:25000, marketing:20000, other:8000},]

const resultObject = {}

array.forEach(elm=>{
  const year = elm.years

  Object.keys(elm).forEach(key=>{
     if(key === 'years') return

     if(!resultObject[key]){
      resultObject[key] = {[year]:elm[key]}
     } else {
      resultObject[key][year] = elm[key]
     }
  })
})

console.log(resultObject)
```

Keep in mind this will only have 1 value per year if you want to instead need to add the values you could:

```
resultObject[key][year] = resultObject[key][year] + elm[key]
```

EDIT (based on OP update) Also theres no reason to add quotation marks for a javscript object in this case. if you later need to to become a JSON object just convert it with:

```
JSON.parse(resultObject) which will make sure all keys have quotation marks
```

Comment: Edited with an explanation of javascript object vs JSON object

Answer (score 1):

Your returned thing likely won't be an Array, but an Object. `opex`, `netRevenue`, `payroll` and the like will end up the keys of the returned object.

That said, in this Array.reduce() is a very useful tool.

```js
let array = [
 {
   years: 2017, opex: 90000, netRevenue: 50000, payroll: 60000, rent:20000, marketing:5000, other:5000
 },
 {
   years: 2018, opex: 108500, netRevenue: 55000, payroll: 70000, rent:22500, marketing:10000, other:6000
 },
 {
   years: 2019, opex: 153000, netRevenue: 120000, payroll: 100000, rent:25000, marketing:20000, other:8000
 },
]

function turnArrayToDataPoints(arr){
  /****
   * This reduce will return an object, and each of the departments will be an
   *   array with elements that look like `2017:25000`.
   ****/
  const remappedArray = arr.reduce((returnObj, element)=>{
    // the years property is unique, so we'll pull it out.
    let thisYear = element.years;
    
    // Now, we can iterate over the properties for the current element in arr.
    //  if we have NOT created a property with this name on our return object,
    //  we want to create an empty array. Then, either way, we push a string on.
    for(let propName in element){
      if(propName !== 'years'){
        if(!returnObj.hasOwnProperty(propName))
          returnObj[propName] = {};
        returnObj[propName][thisYear] = element[propName];
      }
    }
    // And within our reduce, we need to remember to return our object.
    return returnObj;
  }, {}) //<-- this is the empty object we'll populate above.
  
  return remappedArray;
}

console.log(turnArrayToDataPoints(array));
```

As was pointed out, deleting the 'years' property is bad form from a functional perspective. Edited the code to simply check if the given property is 'years' instead.

Comment: you're returning a string rather than the object for each value which is what the op requested (though you are correct that it needs to be an obj result)

Comment: Also your use of `delete element.years` mutates the original array which is likely bad practice

Comment: True, at least from a functional perspective. Edited again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the objects in your array have the same properties you can collect the keys of the first object and use them for combing through the whole array:

```js
let array = [ { years: 2017, opex: 90000, netRevenue: 50000, payroll: 60000, rent:20000, marketing:5000, other:5000 }, { years: 2018, opex: 108500, netRevenue: 55000, payroll: 70000, rent:22500, marketing:10000, other:6000 }, { years: 2019, opex: 153000, netRevenue: 120000, payroll: 100000, rent:25000, marketing:20000, other:8000 } ];

var keys=Object.keys(array[0]).slice(1);
var res={};
keys.forEach(k=>res[k]={});
array.forEach(c=>
  keys.forEach(k=>res[k][c.years]=c[k]));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Goal is to minimize the number of times you have to iterate over the same set of objects.

```js
let array = [
 {
   "years": "2017", "opex": 90000, "netRevenue": 50000, "payroll": 60000, "rent":20000, "marketing":5000, "other":5000
 },
 {
   "years": "2018", "opex": 108500, "netRevenue": 55000, "payroll": 70000, "rent":22500, "marketing":10000, "other":6000
 },
 {
   "years": "2019", "opex": 153000, "netRevenue": 120000, "payroll": 100000, "rent":25000, "marketing":20000, "other":8000
 },
]

let output={};

array.forEach(obj=>{
  Object.keys(obj).filter(key=>key!=="years")
  .forEach(key=>{
    output[key] = output[key] || {};
    output[key][obj.years]=obj[key]
  })
})

console.log(output)
```